# How to tell php to echo something acquired to the selected option

Tags: php

I have two  tags, the first one is to select the brand and the second one is to select the product.

My question/problem is that I want to tell php to echo  inside the second select tag. The `echo`ed option needs to have the same `brand_name` as the selected option from the first  tag.

What I need is that if I choose  Adidas as the brand, php would show every product that has the `brand_name` Adidas.

I have two different database tables, the first one called `brand`:

```
brand_id | brand_name
    1    | ADIDAS
    2    | NIKE
```

The second one called `product`:

```
product_id | brand_name | product_name | product_image | amount | sell | buy
     1     |   ADIDAS   |    T-Shirt   |     none      |   50   |  30  | 28
     2     |   NIKE     |    Shoes     |     none      |   20   |  130 | 120
```

Here is my code:

```
<select>
<option disabled selected>----SELECT----</option>
    <?php 
        require_once 'connections/dbc.php';
        $query = "SELECT `brand_name` FROM `brands`";
        $response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (!$response) {
            $_SESSION['errortitle'] ='Error loading the brands';
            $_SESSION['errormessage'] = 'Something wrong happend while loading the brands.<br/>Please contact The developer';
            header("location: error.php");
            exit();
        } else {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
              echo '<option name="brand_name" value='.$row['brand_name'].'>'.$row['brand_name'].'</option>';
              }
          }
     ?>
</select>

<select>
    <option disabled selected>----SELECT----</option>
        <?php

            require_once 'connections/dbc.php';

            ###########HERE WHERE I NEED MY CODE##############

            $query = "SELECT `product_name` FROM `product WHERE brand_name = "##### The selected option from the first select tag" ";
            $response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            if (!$response) {
                $_SESSION['errortitle'] = "Error loading the prouducts";
                $_SESSION['errormessage'] = 'Something wrong happend while loading the proudcts.<br/>Please contact The developer';
                header("location: error.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
                  echo '<option name="product_name" value='.$row['product_name'].'>'.$row['product_name'].'</option>';
                  }
            }
         ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You can't do it like this... PHP is rendered before the html, so you can't even select something from your select box. You have to make an ajax request to the server after selecting something from the box.

Comment: Look here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Of course i can, it's working perfectly "The first select box"

Comment: You need to use ajax to update the page live with php

Comment: Food for thought: do you see the page already rendered when you select an option by changing the select option? php has already done it's job.. how can u expect it to do more after that? ;)

Comment: its not working as expected because there are now connections to the database and the requier file doesnt excist in the server where the code is....
but yeah i think that i need ajax call but i dont know how to use ajax:(((

Comment: Like its working but i wanted to improve it by letting the php or what ever auto select the brand_name and set it for the query for the next select but yes you have right the site need to relod to load the new data so Thank you now i understand how it works but i dont know how to get it works XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

First: Download all contents of 'products' table, and make script that will add items with selected 'brand' attribute to  box.

Second: (Recommended) When user selects a brand, make an AJAX query, and get all items with selected brand.

Second one is much better, because you will need to download less data, and page will load faster.

Imagine you have 10^9 products, and 10^7 brands(average 100 products per brand)
Using first solution, you will need to download all 10^9 products, and then use JavaScript(which is not very fast) to select 100 of them.
If you use second solution two things are going to be much better:
1. Download 100 items instead of 10^9.
2. To select items use fast SQL engine instead of slow JavaScript

It is not possible to do it with php, because php is server-side. Server is making page code with php, and then sending it to user. It's impossible to make callback to php without AJAX

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a single `SELECT` with `LEFT JOIN`, to get all of the columns from both tables at the same time:

`SELECT brands.brand_name, products.product_name FROM brands LEFT JOIN products on brands.brand_name = products.brand_name GROUP BY brands.brand_name`

And build both of your `<select>` nodes from that single query. To do this, build your first `<select>` node from the query, the same as you are doing now, then in the lower part of the code reset the `$response` with `$response->data_seek(0)`. Then you can build the second `<select>` as though you had done another query.

It will look something like the following code. There are only two minor changes to your original. Look for some comments in the top section, and some in the bottom section. I don't have an easy mechanism to run PHP, so I can't test it, and it might not run perfectly as it is now. But I think it will give you an idea of what to do.

```
<select>
<option disabled selected>----SELECT----</option>
    <?php 
        require_once 'connections/dbc.php';




        // Notice that the query includes LEFT JOIN, to get the
        // columns from both tables in a single query.
        $query = "SELECT brands.brand_name, products.product_name
                  FROM brands left join products on brands.brand_name = products.brand_name"




        $response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (!$response) {
            $_SESSION['errortitle'] ='Error loading the brands';
            $_SESSION['errormessage'] = 'Something wrong happend while loading the brands.<br/>Please contact The developer';
            header("location: error.php");
            exit();
        } else {
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
              echo '<option name="brand_name" value='.$row['brand_name'].'>'.$row['brand_name'].'</option>';
              }
          }
     ?>
</select>

<select>
    <option disabled selected>----SELECT----</option>
        <?php

            require_once 'connections/dbc.php';


            // Here, you don't need another query. You simply reset
            // $response, and then fetch as you would from a
            // normal query.
            $response->data_seek(0);


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
            echo '<option name="product_name" value='.$row['product_name'].'>'.$row['product_name'].'</option>';
            }
         ?>
</select>
```

Comment: But then if i want to echo the brand rows im going to have the same row number as the whole product database rows

Comment: @AssadRajab I don't understand what you mean. Please edit your original question and explain this requirement in detail. Also, it would help me understand this new requirement better if you could show it in the code. If it's possible.

Comment: well if i make left join im going to have a lot of brand_name and if this happens i wont to be able to echo the first Select box ...
im going to set a link to my code source so you can take a look on it

Comment: Well, I couldn't get that to run, but no problem. I think I know what you need: `group by`. I've updated my answer; have a look and let me know if it doesn't do what you need.

Comment: Well i've learned something from your script but this wasnt what i want.....
what i want is that if i selected the brand_name is ADIDAS that the second Select box"product_name" shows just the product_name which have the same brand_name that selected in the first select box

Comment: The system will soon begin complaining that our conversation is too long. If you like, we can move to a chat room and work on your issue in real-time. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165794/php-mysql-html-css-js-jq-wordpress

Comment: I can't... hes telling me that i need to have 20 replation to chat in real life :(

Comment: Ok. We'll just let the system complain. I think I finally understand what you are trying to do. So here is the problem: all of that php code is going to run on your server before the page is sent to your client. So no matter what the user selects in the top drop-down menu, nothing will happen. You have two options: first, have your php build your drop-down with *everything* in it, and then you use some javascript on your client side to manage the bottom drop-down whenever the top one changes. Or, second, do some ajax work. I see that you don't know ajax. This circumstance might force you.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I have to work. But look closely at the answer from @InTeGeR. That is exactly what you need to do. He understood you before I did. If you copy his code, you will be almost finished. There might be one or two things to fix, but they will be minor. One other thing: if you feel too uncomfortable working with jQuery and ajax, look for a forum. I mean a site with "forum" in the name. There will be people there who can help you better, who can spend some time helping you debug, and you won't have to type into tiny little boxes. I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Ajax to do this. I'll try to explain step by step.
I assume jQuery is loaded.
Your product table should use brand_id not brand_name.

```
product_id|brand_name  | product_name | product_image | amount | sell | buy
     1    |brand_name_1|    T-Shirt   |     none      |   50   |  30  | 28
     2    |brand_name_2|    Shoes     |     none      |   20   |  130 | 120
```

I hope this will help you.

1. Step - Create your first and second select box by using name or id attributes. I will be using the name to define them.

   ```
   <select name="brand_name">
     <?php //call brand_name options from your database
           //Sample : <option value="brand_name_1">Brand_Name_1</option>?>
   </select>

   <select name="product_name" disabled >
     <?php //dont fill this select box.
           //Leave it empty, contents will be created after our ajax call
      ?>
   </select>
   ```
2. Step
   Add jQuery script to your page as below.

   ```
   <script>
       $('[name="brand_name"]').change(function(event){
           var brand_name = $(this).val();
          $.get( 
             "ajax.php",
             { brand_name: brand_name },
             function(data) {
               var opts = $.parseJSON(data);
                   $.each(opts, function(i, d) {
                       $('[name="product_name"]').append($('<option>', {
                           value: d.product_name,
                           text : d.product_name
                       }));
                   });
                   //Enable the product_name select box
                   $('[name="product_name"]').prop('disabled', false);
                   //Refresh the product_name select box
                   $('[name="product_name"]').selectpicker('refresh');
             }
          );
       });
   </script>
   ```
3. Step - The ajax.php must look something like below. I have used your php query code here.

   ```
   <?php
       require_once 'connections/dbc.php';

       $getBrandName = $_REQUEST['brand_name']; // This is the id of the selected brand name

       $query = "SELECT product_name FROM product WHERE brand_id = '$getBrandName' ";
       $response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
       if (!$response) {
           $_SESSION['errortitle'] = "Error loading the prouducts";
           $_SESSION['errormessage'] = 'Something wrong happend while loading the proudcts.<br/>Please contact The developer';
           //Below Header method will not work cause headers are already been set. You will not be able to redirect page. So just delete it. instead you can return an error by using the json.
           header("location: error.php");
           exit();
       } else {
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
               $prodyctsArray[]['name'] = $row['product_name'];
           }
           echo json_encode($brandName);
       }
    ?>
   ```

For more information I suggest you to visit references below:
[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
[jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
[Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/)

Comment: But why my product table should have brand_id  and not brand_name? if I do it like this I won't be able to echo the brand name.... the database up there is just example how it should be like, but there will going to be more then 100 product, but I have just 3 brands which mean just 3 brand_id!!!...

Comment: It is your choice.

Comment: Can you Please edit the code for me that the brand is brand_name and not the brand_id because I don't know how to work with ajax :(

Comment: It is updated, for more information I suggest you to visit references

Comment: Okey Thank you, but it still not working.... he enable the select box after selecting the brand name but he don't give my any data in the product_name box.....  and in the ajax.php file in the $query you write "WHERE brand_id" and i think it should be "WHERE brand_name" or?